# Thread not retrieving environment variables

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm running some tests on a system I built. When the test runs some events occur which generate new events in new threads. They all seem to work fine except two of the threads spawned will not retrieve any of the environment variables. It returns null values. Has anyone encountered anything similar with threads?

Comment: What do you mean by "retrieve any of the environment variables" Show us some code and the problem

Comment: If most of the threads work and only a few threads fail then maybe your code or the java.lang.System.getenv() call is not thread-safe.  You would then solve this by loading all variables into a java.util.Hashtable at startup and have the threads fetch from that.